# After a certain amount of operations, the function suddenly "is not defined"

Tags: python

In my main method, when I try to test my insert function, after three inserts, the function suddenly throws an error saying it isn't defined.

I'm not really sure how to go about this. My assumption is that it has something to do with the space of the function being capped, and thus instead of going on with the remaining operations, the compiler cannot continue.

```
class MerkleTree:

    def __init__ (self, rootHash, rootNode):
        self.rootHash = rootHash
        self.rootNode = rootNode

root = MerkleTree(None, None)


class MerkleNode():

    def __init__ (self, value, left, right, leafValue):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.leafValue = leafValue

class Entry():  
    def __init__ (self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value  

class MerkleTreeInterface:

    #recursive Insert Helper
    def insertHelp(self, root, node):
        if (root.rootNode.right != None):
            insertHelp(root.rootNode.right, node)           
        else:   
            root.rootNode.right = node


    #insert function, finds the appropriate available slot to insert data
    def insert(self, key, value):

        entry = Entry(key, value)
        node = MerkleNode(value, None, None, entry)

        if(root.rootNode == None):
            root.rootNode = node
        else:
            if(root.rootNode.left == None):
                root.rootNode.left = node
            elif(root.rootNode.right == None):
                root.rootNode.right = node
            else:
                insertHelp(root, node)  

class main():
  tree = MerkleTreeInterface()
  tree.insert("b", 2)
  tree.insert("a", 1)
  tree.insert("c", 3)
  tree.insert("d", 4)
```

The expected result is to simply insert everything (so in this case, the list should be [a,b,c,d] when I traverse it (I only want the keys), but upon the 4th insertion, the error occurs. Here is the log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/User/Desktop/temp.py", line 75, in <module>
        class main():
      File "/Users/User/Desktop/temp.py", line 81, in main
        tree.insert("d", 4)
      File "/Users/User/Desktop/temp.py", line 42, in insert
        insertHelp(root, node)  
    NameError: name 'insertHelp' is not defined
    [Finished in 0.8s with exit code 1]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you post a [mcve] showing the full class (or at least a small amount necessary to reproduce)? Likely, the fix is something like `MerkleTreeInterface.insertHelp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In the `insertHelp` method, `insertHelp(root.rootNode.right, node)` should be `self.insertHelp(root.rootNode.right, node)`.
- In the `insert` method, `insertHelp(root, node)` should be `self.insertHelp(root, node)`.

You did not get this error while executing:

```
tree.insert("b", 2)
tree.insert("a", 1)
tree.insert("c", 3)
```

Because they did not execute `insertHelp(root, node)`. But:

```
tree.insert("d", 4)
```

Tried to execute that statement and you got the error.

---

As the `insertHelp` method is an instance method, we need to use `self.insertHelp` to access it.

Search `Python instance method vs Static method vs Class method` to understand it clearly.

Comment: Hmm, this didn't seem to work. I have tried defining the function before using it, but the error persists after 3 insert operations

Comment: Hey Dipen, I am getting the same error as the traceback, but you are right, it only occurs when it reaches the case for insertHelp.

Comment: The error should be something different. Can you post the error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User/Desktop/temp.py", line 70, in <module>
    class main() :
  File "/Users/User/Desktop/temp.py", line 75, in main
    tree.insert("d", 4)
  File "/Users/User/Desktop/temp.py", line 46, in insert
    insertHelp(root, node) 
NameError: name 'insertHelp' is not defined

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: This seems to be the right idea, but what's the point of making this an instance method when OP seems to want to use it in a static manner?

Comment: Yes, we can do that. I just suggested a fix which is similar to the "insert" method that you have written.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to have changed it. I remain with the same error.

Comment: The error still says that the method insertHelp is not defined. I am not understanding what part about it is causing the error.

Comment: OP, If you post the actual code, it'll save a lot less of this guesswork on the part of answerers and get your problem solved *much* faster.

Comment: Alright, I didn't know if it was acceptable to do so or not.

Comment: You are doing "insertHelp(root.rootNode.right, node)". It should be "self.insertHelp(root.rootNode.right, node)".

Comment: Also you are doing "insertHelp(root, node)", it should be "self.insertHelp(root, node)".

Comment: Hey it finally ran without the error. I sincerely thank you for your assistance and very fast response time! Can you explain to me why exactly it ended up working?

Comment: I have updated, the answer according to the updated question.